# cannot set height and width of a resource shape in styles

Tags: android, height, width, shapes

I recently made my first custom shape and it turned out really good accept one thing. i can't seem to set the height and with of the drawable resource in a style resource.

I do not specify a height or width in på shape because i want to use this shape in different sizes. So i set height and width in my styles.xml file. But the final result is what looks like the shape using wrap_content as both height and width which i do not want.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**SHAPE - list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >

        <solid 
            android:color="@color/list_item_background"
        />

    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >

        <gradient 
            android:angle="270"
            android:startColor="@color/list_item_gradient_white"
            android:endColor="@color/list_item_gradient_black"
            android:type="linear"
        />

        <stroke 
            android:color="@color/list_item_stroke"
            android:width="1px"
        />

    </shape>
</item>
```

**STYLE**

```
<style name="SmallListItem">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/list_item</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">69.5dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<ImageView
    style="@style/SmallListItem"
    android:src="@drawable/list_item" />
```

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList for more information on how to use your layer-list